# How to know exactly Jackson version in JBoss EAP 7.4

Tags: jackson, jboss

I found out this link: https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_7, but it doesn't tell version of Jackson included in JBoss 7.4. 
It tells only for JBoss 8:

[image]

On this other [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/zh-tw/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4-beta/html/developing_web_services_applications/developing_jax_rs_web_services) it tells only generically that Jackson version in JBoss 7 is 2.6.3 or greater:

[image]

How to know exact Jackson version bundled in JBoss 7.4 in order to check compatibility issues with my code which relies on Jackson 2.10? 
I have some compilation errors that make me understand, version is for sure above 2.10, but not which one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best to use the [EAP BOM](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/development_guide/using_maven_with_eap#manage_project_dependencies). That said it looks like on the latest release, 7.4.14, the version is 2.12.7. Note this may change in newer patch releases. It will likely stay in the 2.12.x stream though.

You could also look in the `$JBOSS_HOME//modules/system/layers/base/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/main/` directory and see the version there.